# codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, django, backend

При запуске сервера Django вылетает ошибка

```
E:\DJProgect\mysite>D:/Python/python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
June 25, 2018 - 18:19:48
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x031DF420>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wr
apper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py
", line 142, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 163,
in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66, i
n __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "D:\Python\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "D:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "D:\Python\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid
continuation byte

E:\DJProgect\mysite>
```

Я знаю , что подобная ошибка уже встречалась на форуме , но ни переименование юзера , ни переименование папки с питоном не помогло

Comment: У вас в django проекте папок на русском случайно нет?

Comment: Нет , я проверил в первую очередь.

Comment: У файлов, которые в ручную создавали проблема с кодировкой. Вам нужно пересохранить их в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM.
Если не поможет - вручную указать `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` в начале файла.

Comment: У вас имя компьютера кириллицей.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а как его поменять ?

Comment: @Wi зависит от версии операционной системы. Набирите в Google "как изменить имя компьютера".

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо, помогло !